# Show div when the video is paused

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my code so far, I want to show a div when the video is paused and hide it when the video is resumed.

```js
var video = document.getElementById('video');
video.addEventListener('click', function() {
  video.play();
},false);
```

```html
<video width="1000" height="480" autoplay onclick="this.paused?this.play():this.pause();">
  <source src="../../video/operation.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: Is that all of your code? You have no `#video` element (i.e. element with ID of `video`). Where is the `<div>` you want to show when the video is paused?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#mediaevents maybe you can register an event listener on the `pause` and the `play` event?

Comment: I guess you might wonder why did people downvote your question Neha. Do not take that for an insult - you must understand that questions like yours have been asked and answered million times before on this site and people are getting bored of them. Note that for example I never used video element before, yet one quick google search gave me the answer in less than a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var video = document.getElementById('video_elm');
video.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.paused?this.play():this.pause();
  },
  false);

video.addEventListener("pause", function() {
      document.getElementById("paused").style.display = "";
  });
video.addEventListener("play", function() {
      document.getElementById("paused").style.display = "none";
  });
```

```html
<video id="video_elm" width="200" autoplay>
  <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
<div id="paused" style="display: none">The video is paused, click it again to resume</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing you have missed the `id="video"` attribute on the `<video>` tag.

```
<video width="1000" height="480" autoplay
       onclick="this.paused?this.play():this.pause();" id="video">
//-----------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^
```

Secondly, you can use the [Media Event `pause`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/pause) to bind with the video and show the `div`.

```
video.addEventListener('pause', function() {
  div.style.display = 'block';
}, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the media events that get sent when the video is paused/resumed.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events

```
video.addEventListener('pause', function() {
    // show div
});
video.addEventListener('play', function() {
    // hide div
});
```